# How best to show message that browser does not support HTML5 <range> element?

Tags: html

The  element, which is not supported in IE below 9, is displayed as a default text-field in IE8. For my application, which also has intended text fields as well as other user controls, this is worse than displaying  nothing or showing a “little red X icon”, as the user would be confused, at best!

Some ‘non-text’ HTML5 elements, such as  and , pair with a closing tag that allows text between the tags to display a message to users whose browsers do not support these elements. (I wonder why  doesn’t have this feature/form.)

Is there a simple way to get around this? (I’ve used conditionals of the form  “if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1) …”  previously to get around a different inter-browser issue, but that doesn’t specify the IE version, and I’m pretty hazy about that sort of detection method.)

(Greetings StackOverflowers – first-time poster here. Background: been self-teaching JavaScript magpie-like for a short time, after learning a little HTML/CSS, and have only a tiny amount of experience with other languages over the years.)

Comment: Don't browser detect - feature detect, browser detection is usually bad. Also note that you can shim HTML5 elements like range with a polyfill and get them to work just fine in IE9.

Comment: Check the type of the element, if it says range it is supported. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. (My previous use of browser detection was to deal with the fact that browsers other than IE made text fields wider than I specified, to allow for a scroll bar they added on overflow, so I don’t know if this behaviour could have been detected as a feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here has been solved in a more general way:

There are libraries that help you with **feature detection** and with replacing elements with more modern versions on browsers that support them.

Have a look at http://modernizr.com/

Javascript-Snippets that can be used as drop-in replacements for new features in old browsers are called **poly-fills**.  What you are looking for is a poly-fill for the range element, e.g. this:

https://github.com/freqdec/fd-slider

Comment: Thanks, bjelli - I was just becoming aware of modernizr, and may learn to use it if I can't find a simpler solution